# SlickSlider slick-center slide animation

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I have slider with transparent background and I would like to animate slider background when hovering center div, but after slider moves, hover effect stucks to all the slides that previously had the 'slick-center' class. Any suggestions how to fix it? Sp far I've tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="product-slider">
    <div class="product-slider__content">
        <div class="product-slider__item">
            <img class="item__img" src="img.png" />
                <span class="item__price">Price</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-slider__item">
            <img class="item__img" src="img.png" />
                <span class="item__price">Price</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-slider__item">
            <img class="item__img" src="img.png" />
                <span class="item__price">Price</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-slider__item">
            <img class="item__img" src="img.png" />
                <span class="item__price">Price</span>
        </div>
        <div class="product-slider__item">
            <img class="item__img" src="img.png" />
                <span class="item__price">Price</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-slider__background"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.product-slider__content').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    centerPadding: '0',
    draggable: true,
    infinite: true,
    swipe: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    arrows: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    speed: 800
});

$('.slick-center').hover(
    function() {
        $('.product-slider__background').stop().animate({
            backgroundPositionY: '-40px'
        });
    },
    function () {
        $('.product-slider__background').stop().animate({
            backgroundPositionY: '0'
        });
    }
);
```

I tried setting 'currentSlide' variable onAfterChange but that does not fix it.

[JsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/3frkrfq1/1/)

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps somebody:

```
        $('.slick-slide').hover(
            function() {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('slick-center')) {
                    return false;
                }
                if ($(this).hasClass('slick-center')) {
                    $('.product-slider__background').stop().animate({
                        backgroundPositionY: '-5px'
                    }, 150, 'linear');
                }
            },
            function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('slick-center')) {
                    return false;
                }
                $('.product-slider__background').stop().animate({
                    backgroundPositionY: '0'
                }, 150, 'linear');
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If i interpret your question correctly (center-images are behaving incorrectly once hovered after they've rotated?)

From what i can tell, the center-class isnt appended to that child and still remains on the previous. Try something like this

```
$(".slick-center").ready(function() {
    $(this).addClass("yourClassWithHoverFeature");
    that = this
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).removeClass('yourClassWithHoverFeature');
    }, 5000)
});
```

Otherwise, just add the center-item (2,5,8 if 3 are displayed) etc with the hover class.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

> slidesToScroll: 3

Your code will be like:

```
$('.product-slider__content').slick({
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 3
centerMode: true,
variableWidth: true,
centerPadding: '0',
draggable: true,
infinite: true,
swipe: true,
swipeToSlide: true,
arrows: true,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 5000,
speed: 800
```

});

Comment: I need the scroll to be by 1 slide.

Comment: reduce the number to 1 as slidesToScroll: 1

Comment: Ok but that does not fix my 'slide-center' problem. The animation still stucks to all the slides.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/3frkrfq1/1/ . Screenshot doen't really work with animations, Aman.